# Equivalent of "Order and export" of Eclipse in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, classpath

I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1 in Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm trying to change the order of class loading. I have two classes in same package with the same name, but one is in my sources and the other one is in a JAR. The class in my project sources has a higher priority and I want to use it instead of the class in the JAR. In Eclipse I can change the order under the "Order and export" tab in Project Properties -> Java Build Path.

[image: "Order and export"]

Netbeans seems to priorize JAR classes higher than project sources by default. How do I change the class loading order?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I discovered the answer while I was writing the question and I hope it will be helpful for someone with a similar problem.*

Go to Project Properties -> Libraries -> Run and make sure that "Compiled Sources" is above "Classpath for Compiling Sources" by selecting it in the list and clicking "Move Up".

[image: Run-time Libraries]