# ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(String)) doesn't work after creating jar file in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jar, desktop-application, embedded-resource

`ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image path"))`

doesn't work after creating **jar** file in netbeans. So my jar file can not run but when I run in netbeans it works perfectly please help me.

Comment: See the [examples cited](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) in [tag:embedded-resource]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Icon Image Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use get [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead

```
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String))
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Comment: well thank you joseph but i tried that too..while using this method i can not run in netbeans also

Comment: Where did you put your image file and which path you passed into method?

Comment: public MainForm() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Lady Care V 1.0" );
        setIconImage(get_Image());
        setTabIcons();
    }

Comment: public Image get_Image(){
        try {
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ladycare/images/MainIcon/MainIcon.png"));
            Image mainIcon = imageIcon.getImage();
            return mainIcon;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: public void setTabIcons(){
        ImageIcon homeIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ladycare/Images/TabIcons/Home.png"));
//        JLabel lblHomeIcon = new JLabel();
//        lblHomeIcon.setIcon(homeIcon);
        TabbedPaneHome.setIconAt(0, homeIcon);
//        TabbedPaneHome.setTabComponentAt(0, lblHomeIcon);
 }

Comment: Mainform() is my constructor

Comment: while get_Image() method is working but setTabIcon() is not working

Comment: **i**mages vs **I**mages in path. You should take a rest, bro :)

Comment: sorry bro i can not get it what are you trying to say

Comment: The path in get_Image(): `/ladycare/**i**mages/MainIcon/MainIcon.png` - lower **i**.

Comment: The path in setTabIcons(): `/ladycare/**I**mages/TabIcons/Home.png` - upper **I**. I wonder if it a mistake?

Comment: well Joseph thank you so much bro.... that was a silly mistake by me... well thank you so much for that.... this is my first day on Stack Overflow and you made it bro... well that is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You must tell NetBeans that it should pack your image directory into the jar.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852802/equivalent-of-order-and-export-of-eclipse-in-netbeans